# Get rows from mysql table to php array

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql = "SELECT active FROM table_name";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

DB:

```
|active|
1
1
0
1
```

I've got table like this and need to get that rows into an array.
Is it possible to get simple array like this?:

```
$array = (1,1,0,1);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT active FROM table_name";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[]= $row['active'];
    }

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Glad that I can help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT active FROM table_name";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$arr=array();

foreach($result as $res)
{
  array_push($arr,$res->active);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks @Shoyeb. But when I use your code it writes: **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in website.php on line [[  array_push($arr,$res->active); ]]** please dont you know what is wrong?

Comment: Change `$res->active` to `$res['active']`. because it is an array, not an object.

Comment: Hi @momouu, If I am not wrong an array is object as well

Comment: Hey @ShoyebSheikh, I'm not really familiar with objects but I think an object can only contain 1 value and array can contain multiple objects. I'm not really sure. I just distinguish them by the `->`, `[]` and the result from `print_r()` or `var_dump()`.